# Prevent users from closing certain application

Tags: windows

I have a Wpf (.Net app with GUI) application that a company would install across their employees' computers. They don't want their users to be able to kill it from TaskManager. The app resides in taskbar; it listens for incoming messages and displays notifications about new messages; user can always maximize/minimize it to see the details of a message - but she should not be able to stop it.

I tried to develop windows service that would monitor the mentioned application and restart it - unfortunately services cannot spawn process with GUI attached.

Is there any administrative way that would disallow users to kill certain application (or restart it)?

It can be assumed that users work on Windows 8 or higher and they have administrative privileges on their laptops.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I just reread and realized that you were not the one writing the .Net application, which invalidates most of what I just suggested. I'll leave it up there in case some of it is useful. But will come back if I come up with other thoughts.

The administrative privileges are what really throws things off. It is pretty hard to make something that an admin cannot do, as that goes against basic admin principles.

There are three way's I can think to do this, two are not exactly what you want, the other is a lot of work...

1) Create one or more background processes that will monitor the process you want to stay alive, and have it restart the process when its no longer there. If you create 2 other processes they can monitor eachother as well as the main process, that way if one of them gets killed they restart themselves as well. This is pretty much what you tried to do before, but rather than a service just make more applications.

2) More simple than the above, but a little Dicey and may not work: Add to your wpf an overarching "try...catch" statement that on exception, relaunches the program, essentially running a new instance anytime it dies... This could potentially lead to massive memory problems as the old instances likely would not clear out until the new instances closed.

3) Take away admin privileges from everyone, and create a specialized group that has pseudo admin privileges for everything the user would need admin privileges for, minus process in question. This option would be hard, and likely lead to a lot of user frustration.

I can't go into great detail right now, But if one of these sounds like a good option, and you want/need more details let me know and I'll see what I can do later on.

Answer (score 0):

A windows service can access to user sessions on the computer and borrow user token and launch an application with that token an connect it to [Windows Station](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096(v=vs.85).aspx).

And voila you got what you need.

At this very moment, I do not remember the APIs I've used but I've used that technique to launch an application for logged on user to connect to outlook of one of my colleague to send a prank email.